# Android - Javascript: how to execute jquery in webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm building an app which load a webpage in a webview.
In that webpage, i need to programmatically click on some links using Jquery.
Now, i know how to execute a Javascript code on the webview programmatically (see below):

```
WebSettings myBrowserSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();
myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Log.d("Stefano", "JS enabled");    


myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByid('myWord').click();");
```

But now, I need to know how implement a Jquery function in my webview; i'm looking for the correct way to manage something like:

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("jquery:function($("#myAnchor").click(function(event){})");
```

And which is the correct way to implement the following function?

```
$("#a_link")[0].click();
```

Comment: If the original question you did was resolved by any of the posted answers, you should mark one as accepted. And if you have any other question, you should open a new one. By the way, the code $("#a_link")[0].click(); seems fine. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If jquery loaded in this page, you can just call this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {  
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                    "$("#myAnchor").click(function(event){}" +  
                    "})()");  
    }  
});
```

Comment: I can't modify the HTML code of the pages because i connect to websites which are not mine. So, loading a webpage from the web, how can i use Jquery?

Comment: Got it, I changed my answer

Answer (score 3):

What's your problem? It's about escaping characters?

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("jquery:function($(\"#myAnchor\").click(function(event){})");
```