# webview.executeJavascript function cannot find jquery- Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, electron

I am loading a webview and on dom-ready I execute a function inside the webview like this:

```
webview.executeJavaScript("$('body').css({'left': '" + left + "', 'top':  '" + top + "' })" );
```

The problem is that webview cannot find reference to $.  But I have jquery in my project. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578508/android-javascript-how-to-execute-jquery-in-webview). You might just need to tell webview that you want to execute JQuery with something like this:

```
webview.executeJavaScript("jquery:function($('body').css({'left': '" + left + "', 'top':  '" + top + "' }))" );
```